# Delete navigation options from kibana

Tags: kibana-5

I wanted to know if we can remove options like "dev tools","monitering" etc from kibana page , `localhost:5601`. I want to have only `Dashboard` `visualization` options .

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found one way to do this by modifying `src/core_plugins/kibana/index.js` , deleting these blocks

```
{
        id: 'kibana:dev_tools',
        title: 'Dev Tools',
        order: 9001,
        url: '/app/kibana#/dev_tools',
        description: 'development tools',
        icon: 'plugins/kibana/assets/wrench.svg'
      }, {
        id: 'kibana:management',
        title: 'Management',
        order: 9003,
        url: `${kbnBaseUrl}#/management`,
        description: 'define index patterns, change config, and more',
        icon: 'plugins/kibana/assets/settings.svg',
        linkToLastSubUrl: false
      }
```

and other blocks as per your need